# PHP Captcha can not be curled

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I want to get context on a website.  But I can not curl captcha on website
my curl function:

```
function titub_curl_array($dizi){

    if (isset($dizi['headergoster'])){$headergoster = 1;} else {$headergoster = 0;}
    if (isset($dizi['ref'])){$ref = $dizi['ref'];} else {$ref = '';}
    if (isset($dizi['post'])){$post = $dizi['post'];} else {$post = '';}
    if (isset($dizi['cookie'])){$cookie_file = $dizi['cookie'];} else {$cookie_file = _COOKIESFILE;}
    if (isset($dizi['type'])){$type = $dizi['type'];} else {$type = '';}
    //$cookie_file = 'cookies/cookie_filex.txt';
    // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6
    // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.
    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!empty($type)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($type));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; tr; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/21.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$dizi['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headergoster);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $dizi['url']);
    if (!empty($post)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    }

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    $donus = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $donus;
}
```

and my php curl codes:

```
$captcha_linki = arayi_al($ilk_sayfa, '<img id="ctl00_MainContent_winCaptcha1_C_ucCaptcha1_Captcha1_CaptchaImageUP" alt="" src="../', '"');
$captcha_linki = 'https://titubb.titck.gov.tr/'.$captcha_linki;

unset($dizi);
$dizi ['url'] = $captcha_linki;
pa($dizi);
$captcha_resmi = titub_curl_array($dizi);
```

what is the problem? I can not curl captcha on website

Comment: Please post the curl error, or any error you are getting. Then we can help you.

Comment: try wrapping the curl-exec in if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl-Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo "no error";
}
can be seen here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Can you please try curl_getinfo and post output?

Comment: [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array

Comment: Hi Hilal, i was looking a the site via google translator. Is it possible they have the capture there to enshure there is a human on the screen ? Then  curl will not suffice getting the captcha or the content. You need to do a lot more hacking and i am not shure its legal either.

Comment: You got it wrong
I have no such intention

Comment: I am wrong post
The program worked to correct post data.
  thank you